# how to add interstitial ad to my wallpapers app

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm new in android development and I made a wallpapers android app, I don't know how to add interstitial google ads while the app user is in the phone's home screen and not using any other app. Any help?

Comment: I would probably recommend that you read the docs on the SDK for google ads and how you can embed this into your application. Have you studied the docs? Did you try and run into problems? What specific problems?

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start